# Why is the Authorization code not automatically redeeming? - Automatic code redemption in OODC - Authorization Code Flow with Azure AD - c# aspnet 4.8

Tags: asp.net, oauth, authorization, openid-connect

I am trying to get gain an Access Token after receiving the authorisation token via postback from Azure.

I simply serve the Home view where there is a button to logon to Azure.  Initially i followed this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp but then tried to modify the code to follow the Authorisation Code Flow.

Strangely it was working nicely (after googling for days) when hosted on IIS Express but when moving to local IIS I am only able to complete half the flow.  I wonder if it's significant that my app is running as an Application on IIS not as a website?  The address is https://localhost/testapp.  My site on IIS runs on port 80 and 443 as standard. IIS is as per (apologies for the heavy redaction):

[image]

In essence the code redemption is not taking place.

Here is my owin Startup.cs:

```
    string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
    string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
    string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];
    static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];
    string authority = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);
    
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri, //struggling to see the difference between RedirectUri and CallbackPath
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/home/"), // do i need this as well?
                
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,

                RedeemCode = true,
                ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.FormPost, // do i need this?
                SaveTokens = true, // do i need this?
                UsePkce = true, // default is true

                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                },

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                },
            }
        );
    }
```

My home controller is simply:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public void SignIn()
    {
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send an OpenID Connect sign-out request.
    /// </summary>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public void SignOut()
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<add key="ClientId" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<add key="ClientSecret" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<add key="redirectUri" value="https://localhost/testapp/home/" />
<add key="Tenant" value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
```

On Azure the Redirect URI is:
[image]

this is the trace from fiddler:
[image]

You can see from the trace that there is not further call to the token endpoint even though I believe I have the correct configuration for OWIN to make the call automatically?

I am really stumped and I would appreciate some help please.

Comment: i have recently created my own instances of the relevant OpenIDConnect classes so that I can log what's going on.  I can confirm that the code is redeemed as one might expect.  I am very surprised not to see this interaction on fiddler.  Maybe someone could clarify why it isn't there?

Comment: Fiddler intercepts traffic by acting as the current user's HTTP proxy. IIS runs as a different user and would not send traffic through fiddler.